# Integrating around 2 branch points, trouble with a -i factor.

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem is to find $\int_{-1}^1 {1\over \sqrt{1-x^2}}$ by integrating $(z^2-1)^{-1/2}$ on a contour around $-1$, $1$ in the complex plane.

I managed to solve it by integrating $(1-z^2)^{-1/2}$, but when I do it as the problem tells me to I have an extra factor of -i.

This is a picture of the solution (as given by the lecturer), and I pointed exactly where I have my issue.[image: solution]

Comment: Imgur was having a problem while I wrote my answer, so I couldn't see your image. I hope my explanation of what I did is clear. If not, please ask.

Comment: Your problem seems to be $\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$ yet you start out with $f(z)=\frac1{\sqrt{z^2-1}}$. That would introduce a factor of $i$ or $-i$ somewhere.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is the lecturer's solution, and I don't know why he never introduces the $-i$ factor, yet gets the right result.

Comment: the factors of $e^{i\pi/2}$ and $e^{-i\pi/2}$ in the denominator of the integrand add/subtract a factor of $i$. The handling of branches of $\frac1{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$ is a bit haphazard. The key fact is that $\sqrt{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}$ is well-defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

If we define
$$
f(z)=\frac\pi2i+\int_i^z\left(\frac1{1+w}+\frac1{1-w}\right)\mathrm{d}w\tag{1}
$$
where the path from $i$ to $z$ does not cross the segment $[-1,1]$, then we get a well defined branch of
$$
f(z)=\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)\tag{2}
$$
on the complement of $[-1,1]$.  On top of $[-1,1]$, $f(z)$ is real, and by considering the residues in $(1)$, on the bottom of $[-1,1]$, $\mathrm{Im}(f(z))=2\pi$. Thus, on the real axis away from $[-1,1]$, $\mathrm{Im}(f(z))=\pi$. We can then define
$$
e^{f(z)/2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}\tag{3}
$$
Since $\mathrm{Im}(f(z))=\pi$ on the real axis away from $[-1,1]$, using $(3)$, we have that
$$
\lim_{|z|\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}=i\tag{4}
$$

Using $(3)$, we can define
$$
g(z)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-z^2}}=\frac1{1+z}\sqrt{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}\tag{5}
$$
on the same domain. Using $(4)$ and $(5)$, we can see that the integral of $g(z)$ counterclockwise around $[-1,1]$ is $2\pi i\cdot i=-2\pi$.

With $(5)$, we get that
$$
\lim_{\substack{z\to x\\\text{from above}}}g(z)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\tag{6}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{\substack{z\to x\\\text{from below}}}g(z)=-\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\tag{7}
$$
We will use the clockwise contour

$\hspace{3.4cm}$[image]

Noting that $\left|\frac1{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\right|\sim\frac1{\sqrt{2|1-z|}}$ near $z=1$ and $\left|\frac1{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\right|\sim\frac1{\sqrt{2|1+z|}}$ near $z=-1$, the integral around the circular parts of the contour vanish. Then we get that
$$
2\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=2\pi\tag{8}
$$
and therefore,
$$
\int_{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\pi\tag{9}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you have another look at the picture? Since I must be missing something in my method if I get that wrong. (I did manage to solve it the other way.)